# How to get reference of child firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get reference of smth3 from my firebase database

```
|smth1
---|smth2
   ---|smth3
      ---|smth4
      ---|smth5
```

Code:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("smth1")
        .child("smth2");
 mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int count = 0;
                DataSnapshot needSnapshot = null;
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){                       
                        needSnapshot = snapshot;
                        if(count == getPosition()){
                            break;
                        }
                        count++;

                }


                mDatabase.child(needSnapshot.getKey()).removeValue();
                notifyItemRemoved(getPosition());
                notifyItemRangeChanged(getPosition(), getItemCount());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

this code always removes smth2.

after getting reference i want to remove it with all its children and values 
Please help to get ref of smth3

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase Database only stores values and their associated path. If there are no values under a given path, that path is automatically removed. Since `smth3` is the only value under `smth2`, removing `smth3` will also remove `smth2`.

This logic goes hand in hand with the fact that `smth2` is automatically created when you write a value under `smth3`. Paths are automatically created as needed and removed when they are empty.

Answer (score 0):

First you need add the Realtime Database to your app by adding this dependency to your app-level build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
```

Then you can read/write anything to your database like this:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

mDatabase.child("smth1").child("smth2").child("smth3").removeValue();
```

It is well documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write).